# Popen and communicate not working in python

Tags: python, fortran, subprocess, pipe, popen

I am using a software for astrophysics spectra called Molly. It is used in the terminal, as a subprocess. I need to execute some commands in that software inside of my python script. So, I am using the subprocess package. I am getting this error and I don't understand why:

**At line 133 of file src/gethelp.f (unit = 5, file = 'stdin')
Fortran runtime error: End of file**

I have tried this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,DEVNULL

p = Popen("/home/ayozeah/trm-software/molly/molly", stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,shell=False)
p.communicate('load average_y_template1.mol 1 1000 1')
p.communicate('@macro_molly.txt')
```

And I have also tried this other way (after looking an answer to a question on this web):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,DEVNULL

with Popen("/home/ayozeah/trm-software/molly/molly", stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, bufsize=1,universal_newlines=True) as process:
    print("load average_y_template1.mol 1 1000 1", file=process.stdin)
    print(file=process.stdin)
    print("@macro_molly.txt", file=process.stdin)
    print(file=process.stdin)
```

The error is the same in both cases. The commands work well without python, so it can't be a problem about Molly. I don't even know what this error means. Any idea?

Comment: The error must be coming from the called application and not python.

Comment: But then why are the commands working in molly if i put them directly?

Comment: My suspicion is that they are being run in a different context via subprocess than what you are running.  Either that or the command is being sent wrong.  

Either way this is not a python error.

Comment: I don't know why, but it finally worked using this: os.system('molly < macro_molly.txt'). Then, what I did to solve the problem is to include the first command that I wanted to give to Molly ('load average_y_template1.mol 1 1000 1') in the macro as well. It's a less clean solution, but it worked.